# Визуализация изображения в QT

Tags: qt

Для визуализации QImage использую класс QLabel . Рисую куб который вращается в пространстве . QImage формирую сам попиксельно ( кроме заливки фона - fill(QColor) ) . Запускаю вращение  цикл на 10000 итераций ( одна итерация - поворот на гр )  и все время приблизительно в районе 1500 - 2000 изображение подвисает , но программа не ломается . Когда заканчивается цикл отображается куб в конечном состоянии . При новом запуске старый рисунок куба как не странно отстается ( новый вращается а старый в конечном состоянии) . Вопрос заключается в том , почему подвисает изображение и не смотря на fill перед рисованием каждого кадра остается старый куб ( он не двигается ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, отрисовку Вашего куба надо вешать на отдельный поток. Тогда подвисаний быть не должно.

Comment: Хорошо . Спасибо . Попробую в отдельном потоке рисовать

Answer (score 1):

Покажите код программы, рисовать можно по разному -- скорее всего вы не вызываете emit update() или что-то в этом духе

Answer (score 0):

Изображение перестало виснуть когда начал запускать весь конвейер по таймеру , по сути что советовал Данил )) . Ради интереса запускал этот код ( без таймера )на Ubuntu , куб ворочался, но ОС потом начинала считать программу зависшей ( программа работала как раньше , но просто затемнялось окно программы )